# SFTP - download different types of files using mget

Tags: ksh, sftp

I want to download only specific files from a server which could have other files too.  So I am using the below `mget` commands.  But if PO*.txt don't exist, it exits and doesn't continue to get INV*.txt.  Do I have to connect twice to the sftp server and download them individually?

```
mget PO*.txt
mget INV*.txt
```

---

I am calling from a korn shell script. I am using the below command:

```
sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - -oIdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa $p_sftp << EOF > $p_tmpfile cd /outgoing
mget PO*.asc
mget INV*.asc
bye
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) aborts on error, if you have specified [`-b` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#b) on its command-line only. So remove it, if you do not want to abort (note that the `-` is an argument to the `-b`, so you need to remove whole `-b -`).

---

Though in this case, you might want to ignore only errors in the first `[m]get` command only.

For that, [prefix the command with a dash (`-`)](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#b).

```
-get PO*.txt
get INV*.txt
```

*(Note that `sftp` does not really have `mget` command. It has [`get`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#get), with `mget` get being its undocumented alias.)*

Comment: Perfect - removing `-b -` solved my issue.  Thanks again for your help & guidance.